# HM-10 CC2541 IBeacon - Sleep issue after random time

Tags: sleep, beacon, hm-10

I use HM-10 board (CC2541 inside) with HM-Soft V540 firmware to make IBeacon devices. 
But I have a big problem: I configure the HM10 as a beacon, with auto-sleep etc etc, after reset, the HM-10 is sleeping and advertising (2µA when sleep) but after a random time (a few seconds or a few minutes), the HM10 wake up and consume between 15 and 20mA... all the time !! Until I send "AT+RESET" for re-apply the sleeping. (and again, wake up after some seconds...)

This is the commands that I used to set the HM10:

```
AT+RENEW
AT+RESET
AT
AT+MARJ0x1234
AT+MINO0xFA01
AT+ADVI9
AT+NAMEFAB1
AT+ADTY3
AT+IBEA1
AT+DELO2
AT+PWRM0
AT+RESET
```

Do you know where is this issue ??

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: Please add all of the code and any errors to the question itself, with proper formatting.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your PWRM0 to PWRM1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Guess the problem might be solved for you but as I just run into the same "issue" with the HM-10 (firmware version v549) I wanted to share my solution/finding:

In my case I have figured out that some logger within my code is sending a string of characters via serial extending 80 char. This is actually also the rule that forces the HM-10 to wake up from sleep. So you might use AT+PWRM0 (which enables autosleep) but also make sure that when sending data over serial the string length might not wake up the HM-10 accidentally. Hope this helps a bit.